# Is an int* parameter exactly the same as a int[] parameter 

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, parameters

**Are the 2 following functions essentially the same function?**

ie, is an `int*` exactly the same as a `int[]`?

```
int myFunction(int* xVals, int* yVals, int nVertices);
int myFunction(int xVals[], int yVals[], int nVertices);
```

How can I use the 1st function? Ie, how can I pass arrays in the parameters? Is the following valid/correct?

```
int xVals[5], yVals[5], zVals[5];
myFunction(xVals, yVals, zVals, 5);

// or should it be..
myFunction(&xVals[0], &yVals[0], &zVals[0], 5);
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `int xVals[]` ?

Comment: @cnicutar yes sry it should be that

Comment: No problem, now I can refer you to [But I heard that char `a[]` was identical to char `*a`](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a function parameter list, then the function declarations are equivalent:

> ```
> int myFunction(int* xVals, int* yVals, int nVertices);
> int myFunction(int xVals[], int yVals[], int nVertices);
> ```

However, this does not readily generalize.  Inside a function, there is a big difference between:

```
int AnotherFunction(void)
{
    int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    int *iptr = &array[0];
    ...
}
```

And in a function interface, there's a big difference between the two parameter types:

```
int arrays_vs_pointers(int **iptrptr, int array[][12]);
```

You also ask about (corrected):

> ```
> int xVals[5], yVals[5];
> myFunction(xVals, yVals, 5);
>
> // or should it be..
> myFunction(&xVals[0], &yVals[0], 5);
> ```

These calls are both valid and are equivalent to each other.

---

The answer to your original headline question '*Is an `int *` exactly the same as an `int []`?*' is **No**.

There are a very limited number of circumstances under which they are equivalent, but there are many more circumstances where they are very different.

The answer to your revised headline question '*Is an `int *` parameter exactly the same as an `int []` parameter?*' is **Yes**!

Answer (score 2):

The question in the title is different from the question in the actual post body...

**In general**, it is **not true** that pointers are the same as arrays, so in a lot of cases, `int []` is not the same as `int *`.

However, in a *function declaration* (or definition), when a one-dimension array is passed as the argument, it decays into a pointer, that's why, in contrast with the first case,

```
int myFunction(int *xVals, int *yVals, int nVertices);
```

and

```
int myFunction(int xVals[], int yVals[], int nVertices);
```

are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct.  This is just to add that you have a mismatched parameter count between your declaration and your call:

```
int myFunction(int* xVals, int* yVals, int nVertices);

myFunction(xVals, yVals, zVals, 5);
```

myFunction is expecting 3 parameters but you're passing 4 in your call.

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting (useful?) points around such parameter specifications:

- if you specify a dimension for a 1-dimensional array parameter, it is not checked in any way against the caller-provided argument, for example: `f(int x[5])` can be called ala `int x[] = { 1, 2}; f(x);` or even `int x; f(&x);`
- if you accept a reference to a parameter, then the dimensions *are* checked and must match, for example: `f(int (&x)[5])` can only be called with an argument that's an integer array with exactly 5 elements (or something cast to that type)
- templates can be used to capture compiler-known dimensions of parameters, as in: `template <size_t N> void f(int (&x)[N]) { ...can use N in here... }`
- for these last two by-reference parameters, you can not pass in any old pointer-to-`int`... if the pointer really is to a suitable array you must typecast it first
- that the by-reference parameters are checked at compile-time suggests they should be prefered when the number of arguments is known at compile time... in practice it can be a smidge more complicated than that, for example a library providing a header declaring `void f(int[]);` could still vary the implementation and ship a new library object supporting processing of a differently sized array (which it would need to detect based on some other argument or sentinel convension) without a header change necessitating or triggering client recompilation (in most build systems)